# UITableViewCell stuck white in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableView that is showing the white background problem in iOS 7. I have applied the cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor] fix already and it works for all my other UITables, but not one.

What is odd is that if I scroll off the screen either up or down it correctly redraws the table with the proper background that we have always used. Only the middle portion of the table remains white after scrolling which is the portion I can't get to scroll off the top or bottom.

Here's what I'm doing so far to no avail (this is the standard fix):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
}
```

I have also used this with no affect:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
}
```

Here is what the table looks like after scrolling up and down (it looked all white before scrolling):

[image: UITableView with white background]

Answer (score 1):

`cell.contentView` could affect background. It is the first cell's subview and has frame the same as cell.bounds. Try to add

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

to both methods.

Comment: This didn't make any difference.